# DirectX12 reflection doesn't detect constant buffer

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-12

I'm trying reflect all constant buffers with variables from shader, but the reflector gives the wrong names.
shader:

```
struct ModelViewProjection
{
    matrix MVP;
    float a;
};
struct SomeConstBuffer1
{
    matrix MVP;
    float a;
};
struct SomeConstBuffer2
{
    matrix MVP;
    float a;
};

ConstantBuffer<ModelViewProjection> cb3 : register(b3);
ConstantBuffer<SomeConstBuffer1> cb4 : register(b4);
ConstantBuffer<SomeConstBuffer2> cb6 : register(b6);
```

c++ code:

```
void Dx12CoreShader::reflectShader(SubShader& shader)
{
    ID3D12ShaderReflection* reflection;
    ThrowIfFailed(D3DReflect(shader.blob->GetBufferPointer(), shader.blob->GetBufferSize(), IID_ID3D12ShaderReflection, (void**)& reflection));

    D3D12_SHADER_DESC desc;
    reflection->GetDesc(&desc);

    // here ok. desc.ConstantBuffers == 3
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < desc.ConstantBuffers; ++i)
    {
        ID3D12ShaderReflectionConstantBuffer* buffer = reflection->GetConstantBufferByIndex(i);

        D3D12_SHADER_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
        buffer->GetDesc(&bufferDesc);
        // here ok. bufferDesc.Name == "cb3"

        // here wrong! bufferDesc.Variables==1, I expected 2       
        for (UINT j = 0; j < bufferDesc.Variables; j++)
        {
            ID3D12ShaderReflectionVariable* var = buffer->GetVariableByIndex(j);
            D3D12_SHADER_VARIABLE_DESC varDesc;
            var->GetDesc(&varDesc);
            // here also wrong.
            // I expect "MVP" first but it returns also "cb3"

        }
    }
}
```

My configuration: AMD Ryzen 3 2200U with radeon Vega Mobile Gfx.
what am I doing wrong? could this be a bug? 
Similar situation works correctly on DirectX 11.

UPD: I use all variables for preventing compiler to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you need a cbuffer array, you will need to switch to the original notation you used. The second notation you posted is the one used before SM5.1, with SM5.1 the [ConstantBuffer template is considered the default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/resource-binding-in-hlsl#constant-buffers).

Still, there is a way to obtain all data you need, by going through the reflection data and checking whether a cbuffer variable of the D3D12_SHADER_TYPE_DESC class is a D3D_SVC_STRUCT, then you can loop over the members.

Comment: To add some extra context. If you have your `ID3D12ShaderReflectionVariable*` that represents the constant buffer (in template form), you call its `GetType` method that gives you a `ID3D12ShaderReflectionType*` interface, and on this you call `GetDesc` to check if the class type is D3D_SVC_STRUCT. If it is, then you can call `GetMemberTypeByIndex` and `GetMemberTypeName` to iterate over the struct members.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed.

```
cbuffer ModelViewProjection : register(b3)
{
    matrix MVP;
    float a;
};
cbuffer SomeConstBuffer1 : register(b4)
{
    matrix MVP1;
    float a1;
};
cbuffer SomeConstBuffer2 : register(b6)
{
    matrix MVP2;
    float a2;
};
```